# ¿Cómo puedo comparar el contenido de un array con un entero?

Tags: java, array, comparaciones

hola quisiera saber como puedo comparar el contenido de un `array` con enteros, dentro del `array` hay `0` y `1` y por cada cero crear un punto con el objeto muro e igual para cada `1` pero tendran nombres diferentes. pero me sale error en el segundo `for`.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= laberinto.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < laberinto[i].length; j++) {
            if (laberinto[i].equals(0)) {
                Point muro=new Point();
                muros.add(muro);
            }
            if (laberinto[i].equals(1)) {
                Point camino=new Point();
                muros.add(camino);
            }
        }
    }
```

Ejemplo del laberinto:

```
int laberinto[][]={{0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0}}
```

Comment: nos puedes indicar de que tipo es la variable laberinto ?

Comment: entero, int laberinto[][]={{0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0}} por ejemplo

Answer (score 1):

prueba con el siguiente fragmento de codigo :

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= laberinto.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < laberinto[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.println("pasando por : " + i + "," + j);

            if (laberinto[i].equals(0)) {
                 Point muro=new Point();
                 muros.add(muro);
            }
            if (laberinto[i].equals(1)) {
                 Point camino=new Point();
                 muros.add(camino);
            }
        }
    }
```

Espero te sirva
Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Pienso que lo que usted busca es algo asi:

```
        int laberinto[][]={
                           {0,1,0,1},
                           {0,1,0,1}
                           };
        for (int i = 0; i < laberinto.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < laberinto[i].length; j++) {
                if (laberinto[i][j] == 0) {

                    //Point muro=new Point();
                    //muros.add(muro);
                    System.out.println("test0");
                }
                if (laberinto[i][j] == 1) {

                    //Point camino=new Point();
                    //muros.add(camino);
                    System.out.println("test1");
                }
            }
        }
```

Tambien funcionaria para `int laberinto[][]={{0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0}}`

Test <kbd>[Ideone](http://ideone.com/FT0PCX)</kbd>

Por un lado si usted quiere utilizar `.equals()` tiene que usar la clase `Integer` si lo usa sobre un `int` obtendra algo como esto `int cannot be dereferenced` puede usar en su lugar `==` para enteros.

Despues ajustamos el 2 `for` que tenia una cosa extraña a mi parecer sugun lo que queria hacer.

Y `laberinto[i][j]` sacamos el valor que corresponda con las itereaciones de los `for` como es bidimensional tiene que usar lo anterior no como lo tenia usted `laberinto[i]`

---

Ahora si solo tiene 1 o 0, puede usar `if(...1){...}else{...}`

Comment: muchísimas gracias, pero ahora quiero dibujar cuadrados con el en cada '0' dibujar un cuadrado azul y para cada 1 un cuadrado negro pero cuando lo corro los cuadros azules me salen muy pequeños y los negro de 10x10 (del tamaño que les doy a ambos)

Comment: @AlexReyes me alegra le funcionara, pero lo que usted pregunta ahora, pienso que tendria que crear otra pregunta, entre otras cosas porque esta pregunta es un tipo de error diferente a lo que me comenta ahora, y ademas dice algo de colores y tamaños y en esta pregunta no veo ningun codigo que pueda estar relacionado, imagino que quizas tenga que ver con las clase `Point` si es asi, intente crear otra pregunta detallando el problema que tiene y el comportamiento que esperaria tener asi como incluir el codigo relevante como puede ser lo que se corresponde con los cuadrados ect. Saludos

Comment: @AlexReyes por otro lado quizas esta parte tenga algo que ver `muros.add(camino);` usted añade camino a muro, pero antes para muro usa `muros.add(muro);` igual tiene algo similar para camino con lo que tendria que usar `caminos.add(camino);` pero esto es por adivinar un poco, como le comente mejor realizar otra pregunta. Saludos